# $(...).modal is not a function when clicking a customButton in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I am trying to show a modal when clicking a `customButton` in fullCalendar.

But after clicking the button, This Error Occurs.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function.....
```

this is my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="MyModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                <h4 id="ModalTitle"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="formModal">
                    <fieldset>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div>
                            <center>
                                <a id="updateInfo" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">更新</a>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the custom button i created in fullCalendar.

```
customButtons: {
    AddEvent: {
        text: 'Add Event',
        click: function () {
            $('#ModalTitle').html('Add New Event');
            $('#MyModal').modal();   
        }
    }
},
```

I try searching for a solution on this site and try to re-order my scripts and links but it does not work.

This is my `<head>` tag:

```
 <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


    <title>HRIS - Dashboard</title>

    <link href="~/Content/dboardStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--fontawesome-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"
          integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--Full Calendar-->
    <link href="~/Content/fullcalendar/lib/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/fullcalendar/calendarCss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Content/fullcalendar/lib/main.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/fullcalendar/js/theme-chooser.js"></script>
```

Can someone help me find out a way to show the modal using a customButton in fullCalendar.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with fullCalendar. The issue is jQuery and bootstrap. You are using a very old version of jQuery. I suggest checking what minimum version bootstrap supports, as your first step.

Comment: @ADyson, Hi I just tested it out and remove the jquery below the body. and the modal work. but the fullcalendar's body does not load. is there a jquery that both support fullcalendar and modal?

Comment: Also your bootstrap is and CSS versions don't match, it's not the source of the problem in your question but it's likely to lead to other problems

Comment: Assuming you are using fullCalendar 4 or later, then fullCalendar doesn't need jQuery. Are you getting a console error about fullCalendar not loading?

Comment: What other jQuery did you have by the way? The one in your head section is very old.

Comment: @ADyson I dont get a console error, but, removing the jquery inside the `<body>` tag does not load dates in fullCalendar.

Comment: @ADyson I have this Jquery in body tag     `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

and in head tag this is my jquery.

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: According to what you wrote in the question you have https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js as well

Comment: @ADyson , yes yes. i just missed it. sorry

Comment: No problem. Does removing the 1.12.4 version as well help you at all?

Comment: @ADyson , I just removed it already, and the error was still there.

Comment: Ok. And have you made sure the bootstrap CSS and JS versions are matching? If that doesn't solve it, then we're going to need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which contains enough code to be able to see all the relevant components, and allow us to reproduce the problem ourselves. There's nothing else obviously wrong in what you've shown so far.

Comment: @ADyson, Yes Sir, same version `4.1.3`.

Comment: I notice you have a file calendarCss.css which presumably contains extra CSS for your calendar? Could any of this be conflicting with the bootstrap CSS perhaps? Just a guess, without seeing anything. Like I said, we need enough information to be able to reproduce the problem directly, please.

Comment: @ADyson , I think it won't be a conflict, because it's just a font for the calendar. and style of the calendar.

Comment: @ADyson, I will try to change the code attached on this post, and I will minimize it as possible, Thank you again Sir.